# How to attach classes automatically by their name?

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I downloaded the PHP Amazon MWS Reports Client Library from here:

https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/182-5103998-0984662?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest

and I was trying to get it to work but it looks like the library is not complete out of the box or there is something that I don't fully understand. For example in the samples folder there are sample functions that should let you get up to speed in no time however when you run any of them, PHP complains about missing classes. Lets take at one of the top lines of one of them:

```
$service = new MarketplaceWebService_Client(
     'xyz', 
     'xyz', 
     $config,
     'xyz',
     '1.0');
```

So it is instancing the MarketplaceWebService_Client however that class is neither attached to this file nor nowhere to be found inside of it. After a quick search I found that the function exist under the following hierarchy:

MarketplaceWebService/Client.php

Can you see the resemblance to the class name? How is that supposed to work? Should I add all of those files using require_once or there should be any mechanism that loads them automatically?

Another one: class MarketplaceWebService_Model_GetReportListRequest exist under

MarketplaceWebService/Model/GetReportListRequest.php

I know that I could create an __autoload function and simply attach those classes dynamically but is this what the author had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has an [autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) capability which enables a function to be called if a required class does not exist at runtime.  This capability allows the script to go and produce the missing class, normally by including a file which contains it.

Here's an example adapted from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

```
// Your missing class is called MarketplaceWebService_Client
// The code for this class is in MarketplaceWebService/Client.php

// define a function that will be called when a class does not yet exist
function my_autoloader($class) {

    // implement the rules to convert the class into the file naming convention
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class) . 'php';

    // if there is a match, then include it now
    if(file_exists($path)) {
        include_once $path;
    }
}

// tell PHP about the autoload function
spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

You may need to tweak the above example to fit your specific code and folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the PHP client library, but the C# library is complete out of the box and compiles from the start.  The MWS team has a dedicated contact us page for these type of issues.  They are willing to work with you through your issues and get you moving.  You do have to log in with your seller credentials to access this page.  Give it a try.

https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/contactus.html